# How to Visualize the model graph of a Graph Neural Network in Tensorboard

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I am trying to visualize the computation graphs of Graph Neural Networks I make to predict properties of Molecules. The model is made in PyTorch and takes as input DGL graphs. The code snippet for trying to visualize the model looks like this:

```py
train_log_dir = f'logs/{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}/train'
train_summary_writer = tensorboardX.SummaryWriter(train_log_dir)
train_summary_writer.add_graph(model, [transformer(dataset[0][0]), transformer(dataset[0][0])])
```

I encounter the following error, TensorBoardX fails to visualize the graph model, refuses to accept DGL graphs as inputs and only wants tensors. Is there any way I can visualize the model?

```
RuntimeError: Tracer cannot infer type of (Graph(num_nodes=3, num_edges=4,
      ndata_schemes={'x': Scheme(shape=(10,), dtype=torch.float32)}
      edata_schemes={'w': Scheme(shape=(4,), dtype=torch.float32)}), Graph(num_nodes=3, num_edges=4,
      ndata_schemes={'x': Scheme(shape=(10,), dtype=torch.float32)}
      edata_schemes={'w': Scheme(shape=(4,), dtype=torch.float32)}))
:Only tensors and (possibly nested) tuples of tensors, lists, or dictsare supported as inputs or outputs of traced functions, but instead got value of type DGLHeteroGraph.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use SummaryWriter from torch library. It works somehow like this:

```
...
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
...

# initializing your model

model = ...
dummy_input = ...

...
writer = SummaryWriter(f'logs/net')
writer.add_graph(model, dummy_input)
```

and then after running your python script in terminal run:

```
tensorboard --logdir logs
```

then it throw link something like localhost:6006 and there will be your visualized graph model.
For more info: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html

Comment: Right, that's what I did, tensorboardX is almost the same as torch tensorboard, I tried that too. But the issue comes when I am not passing in tensors, rather I have graph objects. The dummy input needs to be a tensor or a list of tensors for torch to visualize it.

Comment: dont forget `writer.close()`, otherwise the resulting tensorboard will be empty